# OpenVPN windows split tunneling - route 1 IP outside of VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, split-tunnel

- How do I change the config file in Open VPN (windows) to allow a particular IP to go outside the VPN tunnel?
- I know that if I want only one particular IP to go through the Open VPN tunnel, I can use this command:

route nopull

route [IP address to use VPN]

- However I don't know what commands to use to do the INVERSE i.e. only a particular IP does NOT use the VPN tunnel and all other IPs use VPN.
- What commands would I add to the Open VPN config file in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make OpenVPN route one specific IP through the default route, use the following line:

```
route [IP] 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

This will route [IP] through the system default gateway (instead of the VPN gateway) therefore not passing traffic to that IP through the VPN.

You can substitute `net_gateway` for `vpn_gateway` if you'd like to do the opposite, routing one specific IP through the VPN.